# Launching Winform App Using Static Form Variable

Tags: c#, winforms, static

I am wondering if using a program level static Form variable to hold a reference to my MainUI form is a safe technique, or am I introducing something that can cause threading or other problems? Specifically, I am concerned about calling instance methods on the static variable from multiple locations within the application. As long as all calls to these instance methods occur within the application thread am I safe?

```
static class Program
{
    static internal MainUI MainUI;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        ...            
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        MainUI = new MainUI();
        Application.Run(MainUI);
        ...    
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        MainUI.SetBusyState(false);
        ...
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        MainUI.SetBusyState(false);
        ...
    }
```

The above code accomplishes a couple of things.

First, the application itself has hundreds of different calls to retrieve data over the internet, which often take a couple of seconds to complete. During this time the MainUI needs to be disabled and a wait cursor displayed. Instead of wrapping every call in a try catch block just to properly reset the state of the MainUI in case of an exception, I can depend on the Application_ThreadException and CurrentDomain_UnhandledException handlers where I can reenable the UI using the MainUI.SetBusyState method.

Second, I can create useful instance methods on the MainUI and make them available in a clean fashion to the rest of the application using Program.MainUI. For example, I can use **Program.MainUI.SetBusyState** in my user controls instead of **((MainUI)this.ParentForm).SetBusyState**. But using instance methods like this is my primary concern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty legit what you've done there because the app itself will only have one main form that will only be destroyed when the app is closed. If you were doing this with other forms it would be more of an issue.

If you do, however, want to get rid of the static variable you can do this:

```
   [STAThread]
   static void Main()
   { 
        MainUI form = new MainUI();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,e)=> {
            form.SetBusyState(false);
        };
        Application.ThreadException += (s,e)=> {
            form.SetBusyState(false);
        };  
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  Application.ThreadException is special, it can have only *one* event handler.  You used up the one and only.  Try it.

Comment: @HansPassant So if this is the only place it's used what's the problem?? OP already uses it the same way

Comment: Hmm, you didn't try it.  It is not the only place it is used.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you saying my code is not possible also, or just Sten's proposal?

Comment: @gravid - I'll assume that your event handler isn't forgetting to display the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes there is a lot more logic in those handlers, i just used the ellipses b/c it is not relevant to my question.

Comment: @HansPassant are you going to tell us what is not working here? And the focus is how to set the main form's Busy state, not logging. Shall we also write the whole app in here for the sake of completeness?

Comment: @Sten I have edited the question to be a little more precise. My primary concern is calling instance methods on that static variable from several locations within the application. If all calls occur from within the application thread, you still feel I am safe?

Comment: @gravidThoughts correct. And if they don't come from the UI thread you can redirect them with form.Invoke()

Comment: @Sten thanks Sten, I would have up voted you but don't have the rep. Wish whoever had down voted the answer would have provided an explanation or an answer of their own.